# "Changing" complex immutable object

Tags: java, design-patterns, domain-driven-design, builder

This is the code:

```
class A{
prop1, prop2, prop3, prop4, ...

 private A(ABuilder b){
   this.prop1 = b.prop1;
   ...
 }

 A changeProp2(){
   //easiest way to return new immutable A?
 }

 class ABuilder{
   withProp1()
   withProp2()
   withProp3()
   ...
   build()
 }

}


A a = new ABuilder().withProp1().withProp2().build();
A newA = a.changeProp2();
```

I have immutable object (`A` in this case), that is constructed using Builder `ABuilder`. Now, when I want new A object from existing complex A object, in my case I can call method `changeProp2()`. This method should copy all the inner properties of object `a`, change only property2 to new value, and return new object `newA`.

What is the best way to do this?

Options I found so far are:

Inside `changeProp2()` method, I could copy all the properties - but this seems too much, and also not reusable if I have in future `changeProp3()` method.

```
//option1
A changeProp2(){
  return new ABuilder().withProp1(this.prop1).withProp2("newProp2")....build();
}
```

Adding copy constructor to Builder, that will init Builder with values from existing object A, like this:

```
//option2
class ABuilder{
  ABuilder(A a){
    this.prop1 = a.prop1;
    ...
  }
}

A changeProp2(){
  return new ABuilder(this).withProp2("newProp2").build();
}
```

This seems more reasonable for me in this case.

Are there any more options than this?

Comment: Dirty way would be to use `clone()` and then just change the prop2 to the new value

Comment: I would not call using clone dirty but rather the preferred way to do this sort of thing.  You have to be a bit careful if you have more complex objects with relations and such but clone works fine.  In fact, look up some of the psr7 implementations of immutable request/response objects.  All of the ones I have seen use clone.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of returning a fully-constructed `A` value from `changeProp2`, you can create a method such as `createCopyFrom` that returns a builder for `A`. For example:

```
public class A {

    private final String prop1;
    private final String prop2;
    private final String prop3;

    public A(String prop1, String prop2, String prop3) {
        this.prop1 = prop1;
        this.prop2 = prop2;
        this.prop3 = prop3;
    }

    public ABuilder createCopyFrom() {
        return new ABuilder()
            .withProp1(prop1)
            .withProp2(prop2)
            .withProp3(prop3);
    }

    // ...getters...
}

public class ABuilder {

    private String prop1;
    private String prop2;
    private String prop3;

    public ABuilder withProp1(String prop1) {
        this.prop1 = prop1;
        return this;
    }

    public ABuilder withProp2(String prop2) {
        this.prop2 = prop2;
        return this;
    }

    public ABuilder withProp3(String prop3) {
        this.prop3 = prop3;
        return this;
    }

    public A build() {
        return new A(prop1, prop2, prop3)
    }
}
```

A few important things of note: In the example above, I used a [fluent interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface) for `ABuilder`, but that is not required. It makes returning the `ABuilder` from `createCopyFrom` easier, but it can just as easily be done if the `ABuilder` methods do not return `this`. Instead, you would set each property (e.g. `withProp1`, `withProp2`, etc.) and then return the builder as follows:

```
public ABuilder createCopyFrom() {
    ABuilder builder = new ABuilder();
    builder.withProp1(prop1)
    builder.withProp2(prop2)
    builder.withProp3(prop3);
    return builder;
}
```

Also, if you want to have a method such as `changeProp2`, you can utilize the `createCopyFrom` method to change just the property of interest:

```
public class A {

    // ...same methods and fields as before...

    public A changeProp2(String prop2) {
        return createCopyFrom().withProp2(prop2).build();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Seems that your solution is similar to mine option2. You just create builder inside `createCopyFrom` and I create it using `new ABuilder(this)` (in this case I pass object A to ABuilder to init ABuilder with current state of A class).